# How to bind second level data dynamically to dxi-column using *ngFor?

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular, dx-data-grid

I am trying to bind second level data dynamically to dxi-column.How can i set the data using *ngFor directive?

```
Code from .ts File :
this.SummaryData = [
            {
                "columnName": "Total FCT",
                "propertyType": "Impact",
                "own_PT": 100,
                "own_NPT": 101,
                "own_Total": 201,
                "compititor": [
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 3"
                    }

                ]
            }, {
                "columnName": "Total FCT",
                "propertyType": "Regular",
                "own_PT": 985,
                "own_NPT": 2340,
                "own_Total": 3325,
                "compititor": [
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 3"
                    }

                ]
            }
,
            {
                "columnName": "Total GRP",
                "propertyType": "Impact",
                "own_PT": 0,
                "own_NPT": 0,
                "own_Total": 0,
                "compititor": [
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 100,
                        "comp_NPT": 101,
                        "comp_Total": 201,
                        "channelName": "Channel 3"
                    }

                ]
            }, {
                "columnName": "Total GRP",
                "propertyType": "Regular",
                "own_PT": 51.17,
                "own_NPT": 94.01,
                "own_Total": 145.18,
                "compititor": [
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 6969.47,
                        "comp_NPT": 7979.12,
                        "comp_Total": 14948.58,
                        "channelName": "Channel 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 6969.47,
                        "comp_NPT": 7979.12,
                        "comp_Total": 14948.58,
                        "channelName": "Channel 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "comp_PT": 6969.47,
                        "comp_NPT": 7979.12,
                        "comp_Total": 14948.58,
                        "channelName": "Channel 3"
                    }

                ]
            }


];
```

```
Code from .html file

 <dx-data-grid name="gridContainerProjectiveSummary" [dataSource]="SummaryData" [showColumnLines]="true"
                          [showRowLines]="true" [showBorders]="true"
                          [allowColumnReordering]="true" [allowColumnResizing]="true" [columnAutoWidth]="true">
                <dxo-grouping [autoExpandAll]="false"></dxo-grouping>
                <dxo-export [enabled]="true" fileName="Post-Eval(RO)"></dxo-export>
                <dxo-selection mode="none"></dxo-selection>
                <dxi-column dataField="columnName" caption="" [groupIndex]="0" cellTemplate="columnNameTemplate" [width]="75" cssClass="columnBold">
                </dxi-column>
                <dxi-column dataField="" caption="" [width]="100"></dxi-column>
                <dxi-column dataField="propertyType" caption="Property type" cellTemplate="propertyTypeTemplate" [width]="125" cssClass="columnBold"></dxi-column>
                <dxi-column caption="own">
                    <dxi-column caption="PT" dataField="own_PT"></dxi-column>
                    <dxi-column caption="NPT" dataField="own_NPT"></dxi-column>
                    <dxi-column caption="Total" dataField="own_Total"></dxi-column>
                </dxi-column>
                <dxi-column data *ngFor="let column of compititor" [caption]="column.channelName">
                        <dxi-column caption="PT" [dataField]="column.comp_PT"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column caption="NPT" [dataField]="column.comp_NPT"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column caption="Total" [dataField]="column.comp_Total"></dxi-column>
                </dxi-column>
                <dxo-summary>
                    <dxi-group-item column="own_PT" summaryType="sum" displayFormat="{0}" [showInGroupFooter]="false" [alignByColumn]="true">
                        <dxo-value-format type="fixedPoint" precision="2"></dxo-value-format>
                    </dxi-group-item>
                    <dxi-group-item column="own_NPT" summaryType="sum" displayFormat="{0}" [showInGroupFooter]="false" [alignByColumn]="true">
                        <dxo-value-format type="fixedPoint" precision="2"></dxo-value-format>
                    </dxi-group-item>
                    <dxi-group-item column="own_Total" summaryType="sum" displayFormat="{0}" [showInGroupFooter]="false" [alignByColumn]="true">
                        <dxo-value-format type="fixedPoint" precision="2"></dxo-value-format>
                    </dxi-group-item>
                    <dxi-group-item column="comp_PT" summaryType="sum" displayFormat="{0}" [showInGroupFooter]="false" [alignByColumn]="true" valueFormat="fixedPoint"></dxi-group-item>
                    <dxi-group-item column="comp_NPT" summaryType="sum" displayFormat="{0}" [showInGroupFooter]="false" [alignByColumn]="true" valueFormat="fixedPoint"></dxi-group-item>
                    <dxi-group-item column="comp_Total" summaryType="sum" displayFormat="{0}" [showInGroupFooter]="false" [alignByColumn]="true" valueFormat="fixedPoint"></dxi-group-item>
                </dxo-summary>
                <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'columnNameTemplate'" class="center">
                    {{data.data.columnName}}
                </div>
                <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'propertyTypeTemplate'" class="center ">
                    {{data.data.propertyType}}
                </div>
            </dx-data-grid>
```

How to bind the compititor(second level) to each column.comp_PT,column.comp_NPT,column.comp_Total,column.channelName inside the dxi-column? It would be grateful if y'all help me to get the solution.

Comment: Can you expand on what you're doing?

Comment: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hVmr9Y2REnFkMeXmQWXsvl42dBDKh1RV/view?ts=5ca5a8fc)

Please find the link which will give you clear idea.

Answer (score -1):

There are you can find your solution.

[columns caption](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#columns)